# Why is onblur="trim()" used in input element?

Tags: html

```
 <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" onblur="trim(document.TheForm.firstName)" value="" />
```

In the above element the why is `attribute onblur="trim(document.TheForm.firstName)"` used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove trailing whitespace when you leave the field.

Answer (score 1):

When a user leaves the input field *firstName*, the entered value is trimmed.